# Sharing data across apps on IOS

Tags: ios, sharing

Would either of these solutions work if the requirement was slightly different, such as:

```
 App B wakes up
 App B asks App A for (128bit) data 
 App A does a RESTFUL API call to an external server
 App A responds to App B with data requested
```

this flow executes with two constraints:

```
 on each wakeup by B
 A may not be running
```

In other words A provides a data service (by interacting with a server) to other apps on a device, even if it is not running.

This is feasible in Android, but not sure it is on IOS. I know about URL scheme, UIPasteboard and keychain but none satisfy the requirements above.

Comment: It would be helpful in getting more ppl to answer your question if you accept more answers to your other questions..

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a combination of openURL and UIPasteboard if you need to pass large amounts of data between apps.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

Comment: for UIPasteboard we may also see this link http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/03/sharing-data-among-ios-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid answer, but.. couldn't you just do the data call in `App B`? You can't have apps communicate with each other, unless it's with really small data (data that can fit in a URL). You can see the pattern here: http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/iphone

So, assuming that the data is small enough, you would have `App B` check to see if `App A` is available and, if it is, call `openURL`. `App A` sees that it was open by `App B`, does a data call, and calls back to `App B` using `openURL` with the data appended to the URL.

But like I said, `App B` should just handle the data call...

Hope this helps!